# Old school coder trying to understand Agile Dev

Tags: agile

Scrum, kanban, stories, oh my! I'm a developer who got started way back in the early 90s, and I've started to work at companies recently who have adopted Agile Development as their methodology. As much as I've Googled around, I'm unable to find a *really* good document explaining WTF Agile is (as well as all the terminology that comes with it) and how it compares to old school development. Are there any sites you can recommend? I don't understand the concept of a sprint, for example. I picture developers madly typing at 120wpm vs their usual 80wpm. ;)

Comment: One excellent source is Martin Fowler's blog: http://martinfowler.com/agile.html

Comment: can I recommend books? http://www.agile-process.org/more.html - I don't know what's the best nowadays, but a couple of years ago "Agile Software Development: The Cooperative Game" was a big eye opener for me

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You can, but OP asking for them doesn't conform to StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: @Dukeling: I'm aware of that, thus the comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, the basics lay in the [agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

A typical un-agile process is the [Waterfall model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model), where all development phases (requirements, design, implementation, testing,... ) follow each other in a sequence.

This brings along high risk, becouse when developers misunderstood reqirements, this is not noticed until whole development is basicly done, because requirements are chekced in a latter phase than implementation.

Agile development typically tries to reduce this risk by covering all phases in iterations. In scrum this is called a sprint. It contains specifiying requirements, designing, implementation and approval.

Answer (score 1):

You can start at the [Agile Manifesto site](http://agilemanifesto.org/). There you will find the principles that Agile is based on. Besides that I will try to make some points based on my 3 years experiecnce working with Scrum.

The agile environment tries to create a team that can react faster to changes, that focus on interacting with the customer, and showing working software to allow earlier feedback.

Agile does not mean that the team has to work more, but mean that the way you work should focus on working software over documentation, for example. In Scrum, with the sprints, you plan the development for usually 3 to 4 weeks, then in the end deliver a working software. You don't have de whole software, you don't have the whole requirements specified, but you have delivered something that the customer can try and see working based on the current requirements. 
So if anything changes you don't need to redo all the specification, you just plan you next sprint based on what you have on your table now.

This allows your customer to say: "This is not what I want", as erly as possible (if it is the case) and you will have as less as possible to redo.

Also keep in mind that Agile is not suited for all development teams, so try to understand it and see if it fits your needs.